# How to change Openlayers MousePosition control as mouse up?

Tags: openlayers, mouse-position

I am using openlayers 6.x and Mouse position control.

```
this.control = new MousePosition({
  coordinateFormat: createStringXY(this.precision),
  className: this.className || "mouse-position",
  target: this.target,
  projection: this.projection,
  undefinedHTML: this.undefinedHTML || "&#160;"
});
```

But this works on mouse move event. But I want to get mouse position on mouse click. So I want to change it.

I [read](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_MousePosition-MousePosition.html) that `MousePosition` had a function named `read(mapEvent)`. Description is: "`Update the projection. Rendering of the coordinates is done in handleMouseMove and handleMouseUp`."

But how can I change it?

Comment: `MousePosition` class is intended to follow mouse movement. If you just want coordinates of click event, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html